# dyld not loaded when running CellNet on R

Tags: r, linux, bash, macos

I am trying to run CellNet protocol by following the paper Assessment of engineered cells using CellNet and RNA-seq (Radley A.H. et al. Nature 2017) on my MacOS 10.12.6.

I installed `R, CellNet package, Salmon, and cutadapt` as required.

However, when I run the command (step 6):

```
$expList<-cn_salmon(stQuery, refDir="ref/",salmonIndex=iFileHuman, geneTabfname="geneToTrans_Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.80.exo_Jul_04_2015.R", salmonPath=pathToSalmon)
```

there comes this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libtbb.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/me/CellNetLocal/Salmon/bin/salmon
  Reason: image not found
```

Can anyone help with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem finally turned out to be downloading an older version of salmon (0.7.3) because at present, the index in CellNet is not compatible with version of salmon greater than 0.8.*. Therefore, please make sure to install an older version of salmon.